# Delete class (multiple) in JS with ID (php echo)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to remove class with jquery but I have a problem. Everything works when I enter the ID normally, but nothing works when I call it with php echo instead. Is php echo possible in jquery?

Here my codes:

Note:  is-selected class comes only when label is clicked.

```js
function sil() {
  (function($) {
    $('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked').iCheck('update');
  })(jQuery);
}

function deletethis() {
  var element = document.getElementById("5279_1");
  element.classList.remove("is-selected");
  var element = document.getElementById("5279_2");
  element.classList.remove("is-selected");
  var element = document.getElementById("5279_3");
  element.classList.remove("is-selected");
  var element = document.getElementById("5279_4");
  element.classList.remove("is-selected");
}
```

```css
.is-selected { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-pos="0">
      <span style="display:none;"></span>
      <label id="5279_1"> 
<input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_28_5279" value="1" id="input-1"; > A)
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-17042" src="https://yapayzeki.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/03-TÜR-01-A-ŞIKKI_Çalışma-Yüzeyi-1-1-1024x683.webp" alt="" width="180" height="120" /> </label> </li>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-pos="1">
      <span style="display:none;"></span>
      <label id="5279_2"> 
<input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_28_5279" value="2" id="input-2"; > B) 
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-17043" src="https://yapayzeki.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/03-TÜR-01-B-ŞIKKI_Çalışma-Yüzeyi-1-kopya-1-1024x683.webp" alt="" width="180" height="120" /> </label> </li>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-pos="2">
      <span style="display:none;"></span>
      <label id="5279_3"> 
<input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_28_5279" value="3" id="input-3"; > C)
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-17044" src="https://yapayzeki.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/03-TÜR-01-C-ŞIKKI_Çalışma-Yüzeyi-1-kopya-2-1-300x273.webp" alt="" width="180" height="164" /> </label> </li>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-pos="3">
      <span style="display:none;"></span>
      <label id="5279_4"> 
<input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_28_5279" value="4" id="input-4"; > D)
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-17045" src="https://yapayzeki.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/03-TÜR-01-D-ŞIKKI_Çalışma-Yüzeyi-1-kopya-3-1024x799.webp" alt="" width="180" height="140" /> </label> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wpProQuiz_response" style="display: none;">
  <div style="display: none;" class="wpProQuiz_correct">
    <span>Tebrik ederiz! Bu soruyu doğru cevapladın.</span>
    <p class="wpProQuiz_AnswerMessage"> </p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="wpProQuiz_incorrect">
    <span> Üzgünüz bu soruyu doğru cevaplayamadın. Belki konuya tekrar bakman gerekebilir. </span>
    <p class="wpProQuiz_AnswerMessage"> </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="sil()">Cevapları Sil</button>
<button onclick="deletethis()">Son İşaretimi Sil</button>
```

Comment: Show the rendered HTML and script. Whatever that looks like is what you have access to in jQuery. Server side is not accessible to client side without something like AJAX

Comment: Also if you have jQuery, use jQuery: `$("[id^=<?php echo $question->getId(); ?>]").removeClass("is-selected")` if you want to remove the class on any element that starts with getId

Comment: I edited like this  `var element = document.getElementById("$("[id^=<?php echo $question->getId(); ?>]").removeClass("is-selected")");
  element.classList.remove("is-selected");`

Not works

Comment: UPDATE the QUESTION!

Comment: Ok sorry I add to rendered html and script

Comment: So you click the button and want to delete all or you click a button and you want to delete a row? Can you please show HTML that includes the complete row or set or item

Comment: I just want to delete only the selected ones. If label is selected, label have a class="is-selected" and I need to delete this class with button. I added to full html on thread.

Comment: I’ll look in a while

Comment: Okay I'm waiting to you. Thanks!

Comment: I made you a proper snippet. Your video link did not work. Please tell me what is expected. There are no elements with class is-selected in your code right now. I still have no idea what you need